# Component automatically change its position in angular 6

Tags: angular

Currently I am developing angular application.More Than 6 components are loaded in dashboard based on user roles.I am used col to split the components size in dashboard.The problem is some component is hidden for users based on role.If the component is removed the space is still maintain,its not aligned.I want to replace the space by next component currently available.

dashboard.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <app-date-update *ngIf="isAdminLogin"></app-date-update>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <app-missing-alert></app-missing-alert>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <app-answers></app-answers>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <app-due-date-alerts *ngIf="isPermittedRoleForDuedate"></app-due-date-alerts>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the col is splitted so the space is still maintained when the component is hidden.How to achieve this in html or angular??

Comment: Move the `*ngIf` up onto the `div` with the `col-lg-4` class

Comment: Your solution is working little bit.But the problem is In the first row last col is hidden means the space is still maintain because the col is in that row.How to fix it

Comment: Use a single div.row and put ll your div.col-lg-4 inside.

Comment: Hey I have more than 5 components how to split into .col-lg-4  in a single row.

Comment: Okay, in that case it sounds like maybe you want CSS flex. Are you able to create a StackBlitz demo of your layout, and post the link?

Comment: Its quite complex to create a stackblitz because more components to create for that.

Comment: Can you produce your solution stackblitz.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap 4.1.3

Comment: @Arthi Then use the `d-flex` and `flex-fill` classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#fill

Comment: @user184994 It's working thank you..

Answer (score 0):

This requirement is not achievable using bootstrap classes.
This can be achieved through angular attribute directives (ngStyle/ngClass/custom directives).
Based on the conditions appropriate classes need to be added to the div to decide their width.

Hope this helps.